# .net core httpclient handling response with file attached

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, httpclient, httpresponse

I am trying to get a file from a response that has been wrapped with a multipartformdata

here is an example of response

```
----------------------------584934499238183576109185
Content-Disposition: form-data; name=""

somecontentfromdifferentfiles...
----------------------------584934499238183576109185--
```

I would like to get only the real content, how can I achieve this with .net core http Client?

Essentially if I paste the link in the browser will work with no problem and produce the attachment file, but don't know how to get the content from the attachment programmatically.

```
var response = await _httpClient.GetAsync(URI);
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    var responseAsString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

}
```

Thanks,

Comment: Please provide your current code

Comment: You mean that you want to use http client to download the uploaded file?